# Identify the movie where a man is sent to prison and has cellmate with a calendar tattooed all over his arms

Tags: identify-this-movie

It is a movie about someone breaking into a guy's house, and the homeowner runs after the guy and I think in self defense kills him (unsure about this part) He gets sent to jail and put in a cell with a guy who has a calendar tattooed all over his arms.

His cellmate has been looking for the man who killed his wife in daughter and killing anyone in the process that might have been involved with the guy who killed his wife and daughter but we don't find this out until later.

In the mean time, the two become fast friends, but they are forced to fight other inmates under the "watch" of the man in charge of their cells , he's a black man I believe.

Eventually they team up with all of the inmates to fight the jail keeper, and the guy with the calendars on his arms has a knife type of tool that is hidden in his glasses dies but the guy who was wrongfully convicted goes free.

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 4):

I believe the movie you are looking for is [Felon(2008)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1117385/)

> A loving family man with a promising future, Wade Porter (Stephen Dorff) suddenly loses everything when he accidentally kills the burglar who breaks into his home. Convicted of involuntary manslaughter, Wade is sentenced to spend the next three years inside a maximum security facility where the rules of society no longer apply. Forced to share a cell with a notorious mass murderer (Val Kilmer) and subjected to brutal beatings orchestrated by the sadistic head prison guard (Harold Perrineau), Wade soon realizes he's in for the fight of his life and must become the toughest FELON of them all if he wants to survive the block. After all, what doesn't kill you only makes you stronger. And in state prison, only the strongest survive.